# Как в бинарный файл записать словарь (ключ:значение)?

Tags: python

Таблицу рекордов.

```
pickle.dump(player:score, rec_b)
```

Python говорит:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax (на двоеточие).

Comment: А разве так [словарь](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) оформляется?

Answer (score 3):

Ну если мы словарь дампаем, то он должен существовать в момент дампа?

```
pickle.dump({player: score}, rec_b)
```